# How to reset Color picker using javascript?

Tags: javascript, color-picker

I want to reset the color picker described in the following link. But in their documentation, I didn't find any method for that.
Need help!
http://lauren.github.io/pick-a-color/

Comment: I think you need to set the input 'value' property to the default color. maybe manually

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input value.

For ex.:

```
$("selector").on("change", function() {
    $("selector input").val("color in HEX")
});
```